# increment / decrement a url pathname click

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a site with a URL structure like www.example.com/en-US/some-campaign-2469/.

On my page, I have hardcoded "next" and "previous" links that is supposed to take the user to /some-campaign-2470" on "next"-click and "/some-campaign-2468" on "previous"-click.

I've managed to access the path of the url by using the `window.location.pathname` which retrieves **/en-US/some-campaign-2469/**.

So far so good, but what I don't seem to be able to wrap my head around is how to target the last part of the url and increment/decrement a href when clicking on my next/prev-button.

Comment: So, substract the number part from that and manipulate it. There are several ways of doing this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look into basic string operations like 'split' and parseInt. With those two combined you'll be able to get the '2469' part out from the larger string and manipulate it as a number.

Comment: How do you determine which file to display for any given URL? Are you using `mod_rewrite` to rewrite URLs? (Seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).)

Comment: @showdev I don't know unfortunately. I'm a web designer with just a very basic javascript knowledge. Me and my team are trying so solve this little thing ourselves without having to depend on our back-end team.

Comment: @ZachSadler I'm looking in to that, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `split` to divide the pathname into segments:

```
var splitPath = path.split('/');
var lastSegment = splitPath[splitPath.length-1];

var splitSegment = lastSegment.split('-');
var page = splitSegment[splitSegment.length-1];
```

Warning -- untested code!

EDIT: You'd have to trim the original pathname string of its trailing `/` for this to work. You'd then also have to parse the `page` variable as an integer, using `parseInt`. Then you can add / subtract to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would probably do... pull the url, but I would **make sure there are no query strings** at the end of the url - i.e. `/some-campaign-2469/?someQueryText`

```
var url = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');
```

Then grab the last digits of the URL:

```
var seg = url.split('-');
var pageNum = seg[seg.length - 1].split('/'); //pageNum = 2469
```

Should always guarantee you get the page number.